# Special dependence of product of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f=f(u,v)$ be an arbitrary, non-constant function.

If

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=G(u-v),
\end{align}

with $G$ some (non-zero) function, does it necessarily follows that $f=f(u-v)$ ? If not, which extra condition(s) would imply it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "obvious" necessary condition is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} = 0$.

A simple counterexample to your conjecture is the function $f(u,v)=\sqrt{uv}$ (defined on $uv>0$, clearly not on the entire $uv$-plane). This function satisfies $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\dfrac14$.

Comment: Thank you. If one imposes $G$ to be non-constant is there an evident counter-example ?

Comment: No, not an evident one. But you'll need not just the product of the partial derivatives to be a function only of $u-v$ but, in fact, each of the individual partial derivatives to be a function only of $u-v$.  (This follows immediately from my necessary condition.) Can you conclude that directly?

Comment: Understood. Thank you.